# adding an entity object with navigation property as data source, causing visual studio 2015 to crash

Tags: crash, entity-framework-6, datasource, navigation-properties, visual-studio-2015

I'm starting a project with entity framework 6 in win Form. my visual studio is 2015 community edition .
I want to use data binding with object data sources, but when I adding an entity that has a navigation property, (and choosing a form in design view) visual studio crashes and automatically restart. by deleting this navigation property, every thing is OK! when I logging the "devenv.exe", I see that a "Stack Overflow Exception" was happens.
why this happens? and what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if this question is a bit old, it is google top answer so people might be interested in the fact that Visual Studio 2015 update 2 fix this issue. You can find it here:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

do you have visual studio 2015 update 1. known issue at the moment with project data sources
[link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f27aeb49-35c2-4dfa-bdf4-ebcfb546d0a8/opening-data-sources-causes-vs-2015-to-crash-since-i-updates-to-update-1?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Comment: yes, I installed VS 2015 Update 1, on 2 different machine. when I add any entity that has a reference to an other and contains a navigation property to data source panel, it crash and restart. this problem just appear in design view of a form. when I remove the navigation property, it works properly.